# Clear strange parameters from file_get_contents

Tags: php

My client contacts with the database via service. When I do some action, I call the service URL with `file_get_contents` then process the response.

I think when a user enters the site from google search result, I think google adds some parameters to my service URL which belongs to `file_get_contents`.

For example, 
as it should be,

```
file_get_contents(service.domain/service_name?param1=0)
```

but google adds some strange parameters at the end of url. like this:

```
file_get_contents(service.domain/service_name?param1=0&force=1)
```

I saw two or three strange parameters so,

```
force = 1
gclid=CNC-jvTapbcCFaaj
```

I don't know how can I handle and remove these parameters.

How can I remove these strange parameters before calling the URL with file_get_contents?

This is my function:

```
public function getWhere($keyword)
{
    $locale = session('locale');
    if($locale != "en" && $locale != "")
    {
        $locale = "_".session('locale');
    }else{
        $locale = "";
    }

    $page = file_get_contents(getenv('API_URL')."station_info?search.url=".$keyword);
    $page = json_decode($page);
    $page = (array) $page->rows;
    $station = $page[0];

    if($station->search->status == 1)
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return view('station', compact('station', 'locale'));
}
```

Strange parameters add themselves end of the URL.

***Edit***

I think someone is trying to something. $keyword must take a string which is station name, example, London.
But someone is trying to send London&force=1 so I have to check the $keyword variable.

Comment: PHP provides some functions to work with URLs. Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to decompose the URL into pieces and decode the parameters, change/remove the parameters as you need then use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the new query string and join it to the rest of the URL (no function needed, string concatenation (`.`) is enough).

Comment: Google cant effect your code. Now if your code is naively taking all parameters from the request and passing them on, thats an issue, but without seeing your code there is no way to help

Answer (score -1):

You can parse url by `parse_url` function, remove unwanted parameters or just keep parameters you want and build url back

after using `parse_url` function you may need to parse `query` by `parse_str` function, so code will look like:

```
$urlParsed = parse_url("service.domain/service_name?param1=0&force=1");
$params = parse_str ($urlParsed['query']);
$newParams = [];
$neededParams = ['param1', 'param2'];
foreach ($neededParams as $p) {
    if (isset($params[$p])) {
        $newParams[$p] = $params[$p];
    }
}

$newUrl = $urlParsed['scheme'] . '://' . $urlParsed['host'] . $urlParsed['path'] . '?' . http_build_query($newParams);

file_get_contents($newUrl);
```

I didn't test that code, but I hope the idea is clear and you can amend it to your needing.

Comment: [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) doesn't return anything.

Comment: because url is wrong, use correct url e.g `http://service.com/service_name?param1=0&force=1`

Comment: You didn't get it. It is [`void parse_str(string $encoded_string [, array &$result])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). It doesn't return a value, this is how it works. This doesn't depend on the value it receives as argument.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. As I mentioned I did not test code :)